# Translation of "What have you been up to lately?"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, saludos, preguntas

In English, when meeting someone you haven't seen for a while, you might ask, "What have you been up to lately?"

What is the equivalent question in Spanish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's depends on the formality and how familiar you are with the person. You can say:

- ¿Qué es de tu vida? (informal)
- ¿Qué haces(últimamente)? (informal)
- ¿Dónde te metes/habías metido? (very informal)
- ¿A que te dedicas/estás dedicando? (semiformal, formal if formulated with usted)
- ¿Todo igual? (neutral)
- ¿En que has estado últimamente?
  (neutral)
- ¿Que has estado haciendo últimamente? (familiar but not informal)
- ¿Que novedades? (see comments)
- ¿En que andas? (informal)
- ¿Como va todo? lit. "How it's going?"

Comment: ¿En qué has estado últimamente?, may be used too.

Comment: ¿Qué has estado haciendo últimamente?, ¿Qué novedades?, ¿En qué andas?, ¿Cómo va todo?, etc.